# When exporting an Adhoc Report it gives an internal server error

Tags: jasperserver

When trying to export an report from the adhoc editor to any format it loads for a while, and then gives an "Internal Server Error".

The report has approx. 15.000 rows. But some are filled with large chunks of text.

Any ideas on how to solve this ?

I also looked at the logs but they aren't showing anything. The only thing i get in the browser is

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

The jasperserver.log and the catalina.out do not show any error stacktraces.

It looks like i'm getting a timeout ?

Comment: Check the server logs under [tomcat]\webapps\jasperserver[-pro]\WEB-INF\logs. [Edit] your question with those logs, if you can't figure out what they mean.

Comment: Ah timeout! Possible. You can set adhoc timeout settings in the report server settings page. Try setting it higher than usual. Also, if you use e.g. MySQL, try activating the slow query log and check if the query is running very long and how it looks like. The adhoc editor works best if you use Star Schema / fact & dim tables. Sometimes good indices help also a lot on the database.